# export result into excel sheet from teradata sql assistant

Tags: teradata

I want to export the results into excel sheet by running the query in Teradata SQL Assistant.
I used copy paste but it didnt work
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't give me option for xls file

Comment: Its focused I am only geting option of .txt,.htm and .mdb.

Answer (score 5):

If you return the answers to SQL Assistant you should be able to select Save Answerset from the File menu. You will then have the option to save it as a proper Excel file format.

If you export the answers to a flat file directly the delimited text file can in turn be opened with ease in Excel and then saved as a proper Excel file format (XLS, XLSX, etc.)

Comment: For my version (15.10.1.7), the file menu option was simply `"Save As"` instead of `"Save Answerset"`. For anyone in the same boat, these were my **steps to replicate**: Run query, click into the `Answerset` I want to export/save, go to the `File` menu and choose `"Save As"`, where excel files are listed as an export option.

Answer (score 1):

Select the whole excel worksheet you will paste into and set the number format to 'text'.

Now you can safely copy the data from the teradata sql assistant's query results and paste them into the spreadsheet.