# I have a DB table with a comment column with multi line data

Tags: sql, excel, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a DB table with a comment column. Users input there comments as multi lines.So while exporting this result to an excel, the comments are getting added as a new row.
 How can I copy the data from SQL to an excel correctly.
I am using Teradata SQL assistant and there is no option to directly export details to excel. Exported data to txt & htm and imported that to excel failed because of the comment text format issue.
PLEASE SUGGEST A SOLUTION.

Comment: Have you tried first exporting to CSV?

Comment: No . I didnt find an option to export to CSV first. I exported to txt and then exported to csv and then imported that to an excel. But again it didnt works

Comment: Use a proper CSV (or Excel) export that retains the column values properly. Both Excel and CSV can properly handle newlines within column values. Unless you show us exactly what you did, we cannot recommend a good approach on how to do this with the tools you have available. Personally, I would use Perl to do the proper export as CSV.

Comment: According to the following page, Teradata does have a built in export to CSV function: https://community.teradata.com/t5/Tools-Utilities/Export-large-data-set-to-CSV-files/td-p/46349

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517922/export-result-into-excel-sheet-from-teradata-sql-assistant